# SQL Server 2005 Disable Database Diagrams

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if there was a way to disable the use of the database diagrams in SQL Server. This is more of just an annoyance for me, because I never use them and I am constantly prompted to create the necessary objects to enable the diagrams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a feature of "SQL Server" so much as the SQL Management Studio or Enterprise Manager (version depending). I'm not aware of any way to remove the functionality from the user interface. It would probably be easiest if you just didn't click on it!

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I mostly use my keyboard for navigating, so I come across this a little more frequently.

Comment: If it's any help, the annoying prompt is gone from the SSMS that comes with SQL 2008, buy the Dev edition for yourself and use that.

Answer (score 1):

How about you just click OK and create those objects so that SSMS will not prompt you again?
Those objects are harmless and creating them will make the annoying prompt go away. :)